# Spring Tool Suite 4 not showing option for JSP file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsp, spring-tool-suite

I am following a tutorial that wants me to add a JSP file to the exercise. When I try to add a 'Other' in the Wizard and search for JSP, it is not an option. Spring Tool Suite 4 not showing option for JSP file.
What resource am I missing and how do I add it?
I also have a warning no JRE's installed, is this related to my issue?

Answer (score 3):

Found this solution in StackOverflow

If anyone is having this issue with Sring Starter Project in Spring Tool Suite 4:

Help -> Install New Software -> WorkWith Spring Tool Suite 4
Scroll to bottom and select :

Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development

Answer (score 2):

By default, the JSP files are not included in the suite.

In your suite,
Just go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace -> type Eclipse Enterprise Java and Web Developer Tools (version = latest one is 3.22) and install it

Then restart your suite and check now.

Comment: I'm using Spring STS Version: 4.17.1.RELEASE and downloaded the 3.28 version of this, and there is no special JSP editor option.  The icon beside a jsp file looks like a simple text document.   i'm tempted to login to work to see what it's supposed to look like.  Is there a file association to an editor that needs to be turned off?  i appreciate any help that can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like by default jsp is not includedd in the latest version of spring suite. go to Help>Eclipse market place>eclipse enterprise java>>3.28version and install it, it will ask for restart then you can create a jsp file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).